# How can I independently control a light and fan, where only a single hot wire is used?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, ceiling-fan

The apartment I live in was built with a ceiling fan installed, but the landlord replaced the fan with a model that has a light built in.

He's put a controller in the ceiling that has fan and light functionality, but I suspect it's burnt out because of the dimmable fan controller in the wall.

What's my best course of action?  I suspect there's only one wire going from the switch to the ceiling, and I'd prefer not to replace the fan.

My preference would be some sort of light/fan controller switch, but I'd be surprised if I can get away with that on a single wire.

Comment: Unless the fan switch was put in by you, it's your landlord's problem.

Comment: ...and you screwing with it is wasting your own money, and opening yourself up to having damages for unauthorized "repairs"  come out of your security deposit, so don't. "The new fan does not seem to work, please fix it" with perhaps (or perhaps not) a tiny smidgen of "should the old controller have been removed? <wide-eyed innocent blink>" is all you should invest in this.

Comment: Appreciate the reality check.  Probably will just complain to the landlord, but gave the answer to Mazura for the case where he says 'no'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could (spend money) replace the controller and the switch. Or remove the controller and just wire everything to the fan switch (free). Either way, if the wire is in conduit and you have to pull the fan down, just run another wire.